# Independent unit tests of logback logging

Tags: java, unit-testing, logback

I have some code that logs HTTP requests. For compliance reasons I have to be sure that certain things are not logged so I have a unit test. The basic test structure is something like:

```
  private ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> addListAppender() {
    ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
    listAppender.start();
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger loggingHandlerLogger =
        (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);
    loggingHandlerLogger.addAppender(listAppender);
    return listAppender;
  }

  private void detachAppender(ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender) {
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger loggingHandlerLogger =
        (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);
    loggingHandlerLogger.detachAppender(listAppender);
    listAppender.stop();
  }

  @Test
  public void testResponseCookieKeysButNotValuesAreLogged() throws Exception {
    ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = addListAppender();
    try {
      // ... do things that cause logging
      assertThat(countInListContaining(listAppender.list, cookie1Value)).isEqualTo(0);
      // etc.
    } finally {
      detachAppender(listAppender);
    }
  }
```

This works **except** my tests are not independent. My tests run in series (via Gradle, parallel testing is disabled) but there seems to be  a race so that sometimes logs produced by a previous test end up in my `listAppender` in the next test.

I think what's happening is that test A has produced some logs so the Logger has them. Then, test B runs before the `Logger` has had a chance to send those messages to all the appenders. Test B attaches the `ListAppender` and some of the messages from test A are then sent to the new appender. What I think I need to do is somehow ensure that the `Logger` is "empty" before adding my new appender but I don't see anything like a `flush` method on `Logger`. How can I ensure all logs from prior tests have been processed before adding my new appender?

Comment: Good example of why tests should be independent.

Comment: Occurs to me that I could have the tested system allow me to inject/pass a Logger which I could use in the tests. Works, but somehow I don't like that solution - just feels ugly to me.